# How can I automate data loading into Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, autodesk, autodesk-construction-cloud

Context: I am currently getting a signed URL as a response from a ACC Data Connector API call. Upon clicking on the signed URL, I will be downloading a csv file.

Question: How can I store that csv file onto Google Cloud Storage without manually download and upload?

Comment: A get on the signed URL let you download the file. Perform the get with the language of your choice!

Comment: Hey thanks, the direction that I am currently on is having that in a temp storage folder. Then, upload. Or is there any other methods that you know of?